# inspect the DOM and elements of an application using chromium embeded browser

Tags: c#, ui-automation, chromium

Desktop application use Chromium Browser to provide web browser capabilities to a software application. Is there any way to view source of the page being displayed in an application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), a free Chromium wrapper for .net. I've tried a few embeded browsers and this was by far the best.

As for pulling the HTML, you will need to evaluate some javascript and store the result. There is no built in functionality to retrieve the source. Don't worry though, it's actually fairly easy. See [this thread](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/88) for details.

Comment: I guess the way mentioned, to get the html source, above does now work if the application is others and you do not have the source code. Is there a way to get the source of page rendered in other application using Chromium embedded browser.

Comment: You mean you're trying to get the html from an embedded browser in an already compiled application that's not yours? I don't think this is posible. You could try decompiling it and rewriting that specific portion but it seems like way to much work.